# iOS - UITextAutocorrection background color

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I'm using a UITextView with a background color set to `[UIColor clearColor]`. So when accepting AutoCorrection suggestions they will briefly blink white (which would be no problem if my UITextView had a white background). Is it possible to set the background color of UITextAutocorrection?

Comment: If you haven't asked this on the Apple Developer forums, maybe you should try.  Though the answer is probably "no" (or "not without a hack"), this is a very interesting question.

Comment: @greg I will do that. I'll keep this thread updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's a No. This hasn't been available for all I know. I'm not quite sure if there's a trick (hack) for this.

But, if you do get any update on this matter, please keep us updated :) Thanks!