# Accepting autocorrect in UITextField produces a small blink

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have an issue with a UITextField and the docs haven't turned up much.

The issue: When using autocorrect in my UITextField, if the user uses the suggestion, my UITextField blinks, or more accurately a small white box briefly appears.

Below is an example (which took my 90 times to capture perfectly lol :-0).

So the user has an autocorrect, as seen:

[image]

And if they select it, here is that nasty white square that shows briefly:
[image]

I tried changing the tint color (which right now is `textField.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`) to clear but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is turning off autocorrection an option for you?

Comment: That's what I have gone with, but I did not want to. I am not willing to make my UI have that ugly white box, if only for a second. I may have an option in the settings to allow autocorrection, we will see what beta testing dictates.

Comment: +1 for trying 90 times :D

Comment: Did you try clearColor inspite of using whiteColor. I am not sure but just try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. It was asked a while ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996627/ios-uitextautocorrection-background-color) and [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/609662#609662). There is no public API  for the UITextAutocorrection properties.

While researching for the exact situation a while back I've found that the autocomplete for keyboard shortcuts (You can define in your keyboard settings that "omw" will be changed to "On my way!") the completion background will be clear and you won't get the white background flickering. That doesn't help you in any way, I just found it interesting that that specific scenario doesn't use a white background and the other does.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but it seems to be the correct one :-/

Comment: @JayMorgan While researching for the exact situation a while back I've found that the autocomplete for keyboard shortcuts (You can define in your keyboard settings that "omw" will be changed to "On my way!") the completion background will be clear and you won't get the white background flickering. That doesn't help you in any way, I just found it interesting that that specific scenario doesn't use a white background and the other does.

Comment: Very odd, I do hope to see some changes with this control in upcoming releases. I might send off to Apple to see what the deal is